# Angular checkbox checked and uncheck Event

Tags: angular, typescript

I have created a checkbox (ngmodel)]="ishighlylevaragedmeasure"

which has to display the value "true" and "false" when onclick checked and unchecked. but not changing the Boolean value to "true" when checked programatically .
How to set the Boolean values to change inside ts.file for programatically checked and unchecked .

I have created here change event
(Change)="getishighlylevaragedmeasure($event)"

I have created if else statement that it .

Comment: change should have 'c' in lowercase!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of [(ngModel)]="ishighlylevaragedmeasure", use [checked]="ishighlylevaragedmeasure".

Example:
<input type="checkbox" [checked]="ishighlylevaragedmeasure" (change)="ishighlylevaragedmeasure = ! ishighlylevaragedmeasure" />